# init CBCentralManager: Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth, cbcentralmanager

Trying to initialize a CBCentralManager in a Swift 4.2 project.
Get the error shown in comment:

```
import CoreBluetooth

class SomeClass: NSObject, CBCentralManagerDelegate {

    // Type of expression is ambiguous without more context
    let manager: CBCentralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)

    // MARK: - Functions: CBCentralManagerDelegate

    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) { }
}
```

If I switch `self` out for `nil` the error goes away, so I think I'm missing something important from my conformance to `CBCentralManagerDelegate`...

**Can I use the manager without a delegate; and if not, what do I need to do to resolve the error?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The diagnostic here is misleading. The problem is you can't refer to `self` in the place you are (`self` there would be the class, not the instance).

There are a few ways to solve this, but a common way is a `lazy` property:

```
lazy var manager: CBCentralManager = {
    return CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
}()
```

The other approach is a `!` variable:

```
var manager: CBCentralManager!

override init() {
    super.init()
    manager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
}
```

Both are somewhat ugly, but they're about the best we can do in Swift currently.

Remember that the `lazy` approach won't create the CBCentralManager at all until the first time it's referenced, so it's a bit more common to use the `!` version for this particular case.

Comment: Is the `!`version still working? I'm still getting the error.

Comment: If your class conforms to CBCentralManagerDelegate delegate the error goes away.