# init with delegate: Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth, cbperipheralmanager

Feeling pretty stupid because I had a very similar question not too long ago:

[init CBCentralManager: Type of expression is ambiguous without more context](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53383490/4522329)

This time I'm instantiating a `CBPeripheralManager` inside `viewDidLoad` to an iVar (attempted both 'lazy' and '!' modifiers).

I've conformed to the delegate (both on type and as an extension), but I still get the same error when I try to assign `self` instead of `nil` for the delegate parameter.

```
class vc: UIViewController {
    var peripheralManager: CBPeripheralManager!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()            
        peripheralManager = CBPeripheralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
    }
}

extension vc: CBPeripheralDelegate { }
```

**How do I get self as an instance here,** or whatever is the actual issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your extension is conforming to the wrong protocol.

Change:

```
extension vc: CBPeripheralDelegate
```

to:

```
extension vc: CBPeripheralManagerDelegate
```

And then you must implement at least the minimum required protocol methods.